# Ubuntu 12.04 grub install fails, installing to wrong device

Tags: installation, grub2, ssd

This is getting quite annoying and Google isn't proving to be much of assistance.

I've built a new server and it has a total of five devices.

/dev/sda - 2TB HDD

/dev/sdb - 2TB HDD

/dev/sdc - 2TB HDD

/dev/sdd - 2TB HDD

/dev/sde - 60GB SSD

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 Server amd64 on /dev/sde (60GB SSD). I use guided partitioning and use the entire disk (no lvm). All seems to be going well, it's getting near the end of the install and then when it tried to install GRUB, it fails. I suspect because it says it is trying to install to /dev/sda which I don't want it to. Those four 2TB drives I'm going to be configuring in an mdadm RAID5 array once I have Ubuntu installed on the SSD. Why is GRUB trying to install to /dev/sda and not /dev/sde?

Comment: Resolved.

I was unaware you could choose "no" to not install the grub bootloader on the default screen. It then takes you to a screen that lets you choose which device to install it too. I simply choose "/dev/sde" and everything is working great!

This option should be more noticeable.

Comment: Let's reopen this. It should never have been closed. When a question's author *solves* the problem and *reports* the solution, except when it is *clear* that the solution wouldn't help anyone else, it should be posted as an answer. Usually it's best to encourage the author to post their answer but posting it as a CW answer is also acceptable (as I have done). This does not (and never did) meet our criteria for *abandoned*.

Comment: @EliahKagan TL isn't just for abandoned.  I will vote though.

Comment: @Seth This never met any *other* criteria for closing as TL, either (as I suspect you agree, having reopen-voted). The key point is that this is an answered question and the question and answer are meaningful and will likely be helpful to other users. It's true that if the answer were something like "I gave up" then it should be TL even though it's not abandoned. But nothing like that applies here.

Answer (score 4):

The OP [solved the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136781/ubuntu-12-04-grub-install-fails-installing-to-wrong-device#comment163129_136781) and gave the solution in a comment:

> Resolved. I was unaware you could choose "no" to not install the grub
>   bootloader on the default screen. It then takes you to a screen that
>   lets you choose which device to install it too. I simply choose
>   "/dev/sde" and everything is working great! This option should be more
>   noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, and 3 installs later finally found this post. It would be nice if they would make it more clear what answering no to the GRUB install means.

I alternatively you can just let the install finish, and then boot from install disk, followed by selecting rescue a broken system. follow the prompts and eventually you can get to a menu that will allow you to re-install GRUB, and specify which device to use.